# Can ssh to virtual machine on local network but cannot open website

Tags: networking

I have a mikrotik router with default configuration.
I also have 2 computers that are connected to the router.

On computer A i install proxmox and start one linux 20.04 mini virtual machine
On computer B i have a windows 10

Both the the VM (wich is inside computer A) and computer B are in the same network 192.168.88.xxx

My problem is when i start a web server on the VM i cannot open the web page with computer B
But i can SSH to that VM.

What should i do so i can open that webpage on my VM?

Comment: I guess Proxmox is filtering all incoming ports except a few ones like the SSH port, and that can be configured in Proxmox. Anyway, if you have SSH you could also create a SSH port forwarding towards the web port

Comment: I think Proxmox just bridges the interface by default. Ports 80, 443, etc might need to be opened on the vm using ufw.

Comment: @lordcheeto if i make a dst-NAT  on my mikrotik i can access that web server (open the website) over the internet. All of the other devices that are in the same network  (phone connected trough wifi to mikrotik )192.168.88.xxx still cannot access that web server :/

Answer (score 1):

tldr. for those visiting this page and you have a service that is hosted from a docker container, make sure after docker installation do a `reboot` or `systemctl restart docker`.  I thought i had a ufw issue, but all I needed was a reboot.

--

In case anyone visits this page and you are using services from within a docker container, you should first test if port is opened by spining up a service outside the container, for example:

`python3 -m http.server 8000`

Then check if port is listening in host machine:

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Then do a telnet at client side to check if port can be connected.
`telnet $MYHOST 8000`

If telnet doesn't work, then you have a firewall issue.

If telnet works then try to start the service within the container (for me I had to do a reboot, as docker port binding only worked after a reboot!)

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.9.1-gpu-jupyter bash
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

if telnet connot reach the http.server outside the container, then you can conclude you likely have a ufw/iptables issues, if so, then you can tinker with the [`ufw/iptables`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090122/ufw-what-exactly-is-it) settings in the vm.

If the host is a proxmox vm, you should either verify firewall is disabled at all levels or [tinker with firewall settings](https://dannyda.com/2021/10/10/how-to-use-proxmox-ve-pve-firewall-ipset-alias-security-group-etc-basics-about-pve-firewall/) at all levels - datacenter,node and vm.